# Inherited properties read by Spring @Value are null

Tags: java, spring, selenium, testng

I am trying to use some properties read by spring via @Value in a child class. These properties are read correctly in the parent class but end up null in the child one. I am using annotation config not xml config.

For example I am trying to use the property reportType from WebTemplate in TestListeners that extends WebTemplate:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class WebTemplate extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    protected SeleniumDriver driver;

    @Value("${environment.url}")
    protected String environmentUrl;

    @Value("${report.type}")
    protected String reportType;

    @Value("${auto.open.report}")
    protected String autoOpenReport;}
```

Here the properties end up null. If I use them in WebTemplate all is fine and working.

```
public class TestListener extends WebTemplate implements ITestListener {    
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
                System.out.println(reportType);
                System.out.println(autoOpenReport);
```

Also I  thought about the Webtemplate Object being destroyed sometime during the test cycle and tried to store them on the child class on start of each test calling them from super. This also didn't work:

```
public class TestListener extends WebTemplate implements ITestListener {

    private String reportType;
    private String autoOpenReport;

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {

        this.reportType = super.reportType;
        this.autoOpenReport = super.autoOpenReport;
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Ofcourse they are `null` the `TestListener` isn't controlled by Spring and as such nothing will be injected.

Comment: I know that TestListener is not managed by spring but WebTemplate is. The injection is being done in the spring managed class. TestListener only inherits the injected values. Right?

Comment: No it isn’t. The fact that a class has annotations doesn’t mean it is spring managed. Next to that extend a class doesn’t make it managed either. The test listener isn’t managed and thus nothing spring does Will be applied. It Will be for the test class but not the listener.

Comment: @M.Deinum - You should probably add your observations as an answer so that this question gets closed out. As you rightly said, TestNG listener instantiation and lifecycle are outside of the scope of spring and its TestNG that manages them. So those values would obviously be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** After some investigation found out that the problem actually was caused by spring. Class WebTemplate is annotated with `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`. According to what I understood this destroys the entire spring environment immediately after each test and before entering listeners. So when getting in respective testNg listeners, everything spring managed was gone.

My interest was to have only PageObjects Autowired in test classes so I ended up removing from spring environment everything which is not PageObject.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 classes each of which extend `WebTemplate` however one of them isn't managed by Spring and thus will not get injected/processed. The fact that you extend a class that is managed by Spring doesn't automatically make the instance created managed by Spring.

YOu have 2 classes, thus 2 different objects and they don't share the same `WebTemplate` properties. They are 2 distinct classes and thus instances.